# jta transcations

Tags: java, jpa, jta

I have a code for jta transcations as follows:

```
try{
  //start jta user transcation utx


//commit utx

}catch(Exception ex){
   try{
     //rollback utx
   }catch(Exception){
    //print error "cannot rollback
   }
}
finally{
  if(null != utx && utx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE){
                    utx.commit();
  }
}
```

I am not understanding why utx is commited in finally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commit in `finally` block is only called if the transaction status is `STATUS_ACTIVE`, meaning it has neither been committed nor rollbacked. it looks like a security to ensure the transaction is either rollbacked or committed at the end of the method, in case `utx.commit()` was forgotten in the method try block.

Comment: thanks: can u please  tell me what will be the state of transcation after rollback and after commit?Can i skip the code in finally block as i have utx.commit in try and utx in catch?

Comment: It it is documented in the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/Status.html

Comment: i saw that document it says"A transaction is associated with the target object and it is in the active state. An implementation returns this status after a transaction has been started and prior to a Coordinator issuing any prepares, unless the transaction has been marked for rollback".Am not getting what will be the state of transcation after commit

Comment: from my link: static int  STATUS_COMMITTED
          A transaction is associated with the target object and it has been committed.

Comment: thanks:Can i skip the code in finally block as i have utx.commit in try and utx.rollback in catch

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not a good practice to do such commit in the finally block. There is a risk of committing a half-way work which would be dangerous for most purposes. A rollback would be a better option after checking the state of the transaction to be ACTIVE.

HTH.

Thanks,
Nitin